# Rotate a UIImageView with a touch gesture - iphone dev

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, touch, rotation, gesture

Been having real trouble with this one and wondered if someone may have found a solution to this issue.

I would like to be able to rotate a UIImageView using a touch gesture

-> So when the user places two fingers on the touch area and rotates their fingers the UIImageView will rotate with them (Rotating in whatever direction the user moves their fingers)

I can do this but with one issue.... as the UIImageView rotates it does not keep its shape.  It seems to skew?? It is really strange and i can not understand why it is happening.

So if i start with an equal sided square... as i rotate it does not remain as an equal sided square the sides seem to skew and not remain equal.

SOOOO i was wondering if anyone has come across this issue, or if anyone has successfully rotated a UIImageView with a touch gesture without it skewing.

Any help regarding this issue is highly appreciated.

Cheers

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give us some more information, like the rotation code?

Hopefully you're doing something like the following:

```
[imageView setTransform: CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2)];
```